# Error during readThrough operation in Apache ignite

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I have implemented **preload** and **readThrough** operations for my database by referring to demo example at [schema-import](https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples/schema-import/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/schema).  I am getting following error while **readThrough** operation in Apache ignite. I am trying to read data from oracle database. I was able to **preload** data from database but while reading record I am getting following error.

```
[18:50:42,299][SEVERE][sys-#97%null%][GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture] Failed to get values from dht cache [fut=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Collection reducer: null, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=true, cancelled=false, err=class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find mapping description [cache=WarehouseCache, typeId=class WarehouseKey]. Please configure JdbcType to associate cache 'WarehouseCache' with JdbcPojoStore., futs=[false]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find mapping description [cache=WarehouseCache, typeId=class WarehouseKey]. Please configure JdbcType to associate cache 'WarehouseCache' with JdbcPojoStore.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadFromStore(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:337)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.load(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadAllFromStore(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadAll(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:392)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$16.call(GridCacheAdapter.java:1985)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$16.call(GridCacheAdapter.java:1983)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6521)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$2.body(GridClosureProcessor.java:922)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.cache.integration.CacheLoaderException: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find mapping description [cache=WarehouseCache, typeId=class WarehouseKey]. Please configure JdbcType to associate cache 'WarehouseCache' with JdbcPojoStore.
... 12 more
Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find mapping description [cache=WarehouseCache, typeId=class WarehouseKey]. Please configure JdbcType to associate cache 'WarehouseCache' with JdbcPojoStore.
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.entryMapping(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:693)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.load(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:813)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoreBalancingWrapper.load(CacheStoreBalancingWrapper.java:97)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadFromStore(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:326)
... 11 more
[18:50:42] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:02:031]
Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.integration.CacheLoaderException: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find mapping description [cache=WarehouseCache, typeId=class WarehouseKey]. Please configure JdbcType to associate cache 'WarehouseCache' with JdbcPojoStore.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadFromStore(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:337)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.load(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:293)
     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadAllFromStore(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:426)
     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadAll(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:392)
     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$16.call(GridCacheAdapter.java:1985)
     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$16.call(GridCacheAdapter.java:1983)
     at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6521)
     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$2.body(GridClosureProcessor.java:922)
     at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to find mapping description [cache=WarehouseCache, typeId=class WarehouseKey]. Please configure JdbcType to associate cache 'WarehouseCache' with JdbcPojoStore.
     at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.entryMapping(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:693)
     at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.load(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:813)
     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoreBalancingWrapper.load(CacheStoreBalancingWrapper.java:97)
     at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadFromStore(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:326)
... 11 more
```

I have used following CacheConfig file,

```js
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */



import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.ignite.cache.*;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.*;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.*;

/**
 * CacheConfig definition.
 *
 * Code generated by Apache Ignite Schema Import utility: 10/21/2016.
 */
public class CacheConfig {
  

    /**
     * Create JDBC type for WAREHOUSE.
     *
     * @param cacheName Cache name.
     * @return Configured JDBC type.
     */
    private static JdbcType jdbcTypeWarehouse(String cacheName) {
        JdbcType jdbcType = new JdbcType();

        jdbcType.setCacheName(cacheName);
        jdbcType.setDatabaseSchema("C##TPCCTEST");
        jdbcType.setDatabaseTable("WAREHOUSE");
        jdbcType.setKeyType("org.apache.ignite.WarehouseKey");
        jdbcType.setValueType("org.apache.ignite.Warehouse");

        // Key fields for WAREHOUSE.
        Collection<JdbcTypeField> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        keys.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "W_ID", int.class, "wId"));
        jdbcType.setKeyFields(keys.toArray(new JdbcTypeField[keys.size()]));

        // Value fields for WAREHOUSE.
        Collection<JdbcTypeField> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "W_ID", int.class, "wId"));
        vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "W_NAME", String.class, "wName"));
        vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "W_STREET_1", String.class, "wStreet1"));
        vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "W_STREET_2", String.class, "wStreet2"));
        vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "W_CITY", String.class, "wCity"));
        vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.CHAR, "W_STATE", String.class, "wState"));
        vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.CHAR, "W_ZIP", String.class, "wZip"));
        vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.FLOAT, "W_TAX", Double.class, "wTax"));
        vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.FLOAT, "W_YTD", Double.class, "wYtd"));
        jdbcType.setValueFields(vals.toArray(new JdbcTypeField[vals.size()]));

        return jdbcType;
    }

    /**
     * Create SQL Query descriptor for WAREHOUSE.
     *
     * @return Configured query entity.
     */
    private static QueryEntity queryEntityWarehouse() {
        QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity();

        qryEntity.setKeyType("org.apache.ignite.WarehouseKey");
        qryEntity.setValueType("org.apache.ignite.Warehouse");

        // Query fields for WAREHOUSE.
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        fields.put("wId", "java.lang.Integer");
        fields.put("wName", "java.lang.String");
        fields.put("wStreet1", "java.lang.String");
        fields.put("wStreet2", "java.lang.String");
        fields.put("wCity", "java.lang.String");
        fields.put("wState", "java.lang.String");
        fields.put("wZip", "java.lang.String");
        fields.put("wTax", "java.lang.Double");
        fields.put("wYtd", "java.lang.Double");

        qryEntity.setFields(fields);

        // Aliases for fields.
        Map<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<>();

        aliases.put("wId", "W_ID");
        aliases.put("wName", "W_NAME");
        aliases.put("wStreet1", "W_STREET_1");
        aliases.put("wStreet2", "W_STREET_2");
        aliases.put("wCity", "W_CITY");
        aliases.put("wState", "W_STATE");
        aliases.put("wZip", "W_ZIP");
        aliases.put("wTax", "W_TAX");
        aliases.put("wYtd", "W_YTD");

        qryEntity.setAliases(aliases);

        // Indexes for WAREHOUSE.
        Collection<QueryIndex> idxs = new ArrayList<>();

        idxs.add(new QueryIndex("wId", true, "SYS_C0011180"));

        qryEntity.setIndexes(idxs);

        return qryEntity;
    }

    /**
     * Configure cache.
     *
     * @param cacheName Cache name.
     * @param storeFactory Cache store factory.
     * @return Cache configuration.
     */
    public static <K, V> CacheConfiguration<K, V> cache(String cacheName, CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<K, V> storeFactory) {
        if (storeFactory == null)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cache store factory cannot be null.");

        CacheConfiguration<K, V> ccfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(cacheName);

        ccfg.setCacheStoreFactory(storeFactory);
        ccfg.setReadThrough(true);
        ccfg.setWriteThrough(true);

        // Configure JDBC types. 
        Collection<JdbcType> jdbcTypes = new ArrayList<>();

        
        jdbcTypes.add(jdbcTypeWarehouse(cacheName));

        storeFactory.setTypes(jdbcTypes.toArray(new JdbcType[jdbcTypes.size()]));
        
        // Configure query entities. 
        Collection<QueryEntity> qryEntities = new ArrayList<>();

        
        qryEntities.add(queryEntityWarehouse());

        ccfg.setQueryEntities(qryEntities);

        return ccfg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your configuration?

Comment: I have attached Cache Configuration file that I have used in my post.

Comment: Could you also specify what version of Ignite and what RDBMS you are using? This will help us to reproduce.

Comment: Apache Ignite version 1.7.0 and Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 64 bit

Comment: We are looking into this. Meanwhile could you try [Web Console](https://console.gridgain.com/configuration/clusters) instead of schema-import utility? Web console code generator is more advanced.

Comment: It is possible to provide a DDL for table in Oracle and generated POJO files? Could you upload them to external resource like dropbox?